# Regular expressions Python. Matching words in a text file with 1 or more vowels depending on input?

Tags: python, regex

I have a `.txt` file and the goal is to find all the words in the file containing n vowels using regular expressions only.

```
import re
def main():
    n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    file = input("Enter file name: ")
    f = open(file,'r')
    print(re.findall("[A-Za-z]*[AEIOUaeiou]"+str({n})+"[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*",f.read()))
    f.close()

main()
```

When I put in 1 for n I get every word with a vowel. But when I put in 2 I only get words that have vowels clumped together for example the word book. This happens for what ever number for n. I've tried numerous ways and just can't figure it out.

I need help on how to find a word that has 2 vowels (or more) that aren't just clumped together.
E.g for n = 2, `['these','look','hello']`

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Clarification question:  Does "look" qualify for n=2 since the vowels are adjacent?

Comment: Yes it does. The problem was that it only took adjacent vowels but I have it working now and it takes both vowels that are adjacent and spread apart within a word thanks to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4315854/icylogic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a special n

```
re.findall("\s?(" + "[A-Za-z]*[AEIOUaeiou]"*n + "[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*)", f.read())
```

eg

```
>>> re.findall("\s?(" + "[A-Za-z]*[AEIOUaeiou]"*2 + "[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*)", "bool sjalkdj tehere")
['boo', 'tehere']
>>> re.findall("\s?(" + "[A-Za-z]*[AEIOUaeiou]"*3 + "[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*)", "bool sjalkdj tehere")
['tehere']
```

Comment: This fixed it but all i did to the program i posted was take out the +str({n}) and insert the *n and it works as I hoped.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not a good approach for this problem. I would suggest:

```
vowels = 'AEIOUaeiou'
sum(some_string.count(v) for v in vowels)
```

This will return the number of vowels in `some_string`.

This regex:

```
[A-Za-z]*[AEIOUaeiou]"+str({n})+"[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*
```

matches all strings that might begin with `a-zA-Z` then must have vowel, then the string itself and then it might have `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it's mandatory to do it with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED - I think understand your use case a bit more now, so have readjusted the function correspondingly.

```
import re

def countVowelClumps(text):
  return len(re.findall(r'([AEIOUaeiou])', text))
```

This is just a strict vowel count now.

Answer (score 0):

This will find words that contain `n` or more vowels (if I'm not mistaken). Is that what you want? (your question's title seems to indicate so)

```
import re
a = ("Nx Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do"
    " eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim"
    " veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea"
    " commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate"
    " velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint"
    " occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt"
    " mollit anim id est laborum XXX")

n = 4
rx = re.compile(r'(\w*([aeiou]\w*){%s})' % n)
found = []
for block in re.findall(rx, a):
    found.append(block[0])
print found
```

Outputs:

```
['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'eiusmod', 'incididunt', 'aliqua',
 'exercitation', 'aliquip', 'consequat', 'reprehenderit', 'voluptate',
 'pariatur', 'occaecat', 'cupidatat', 'officia']
```